# How to get number of constraints from Cplex

Tags: c++, modeling, linear-programming, cplex

I have a long program that I've written in C++ and I'm using `ILOG Cplex12.5 Solver` to solve it.
How can I get total the number of constraints? Is there a function for it?

Answer (score 3):

Once you extracted the model (`IloModel`) in a `IloCplex` object (you should do that at some point in your program to solve the model), you can call `IloCplex::getNrows` to get the total number of rows (constraints) of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a class IloModel::Iterator class that lets you visit the IloExtractable objects in an IloModel object.  The IloExtractable has a method asConstraint that will return an empty handle if the extractable is not a constraint.  The getImpl() method for any ILOG concert handle will return 0.  So you can iterate across all extractable objects and count the ones who's asConstraint function don't return an empty handle.

```
#include <ilconcert/ilomodel.h>

unsigned getNumConstraints(IloModel m)
{
  unsigned count = 0;
  IloModel::Iterator iter(m);
  while (iter.ok()) {
    if ((*iter).asConstraint().getImpl()) {
      ++count;
    }
    ++iter;
  }
  return count;
}
```